# How do you use positional in Scala parser with files?

Tags: parsing, scala

I'd like to get position information using the positional parser and Positional trait.  I'd like to read the file Im parsing into a string (or something I can convert to a string) and then parse it while retaining the position information.  Here's what I've found on 'positional':

https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Parsing

...which off-handedly mentions StreamReader and CharArrayReader.  Are there other options?  Reading my file into something that can be used with a CharArrayReader may be what I need.  If so, how does that work?  If not, what *should* I be doing?

(FYI, StreamReader is out because I want to read and keep the file long before I parse it, not because I want to waste memory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct your favorite browser to the [ScalaDoc HTML](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html) and navigate to the package `scala.util.parsing.input` where you'll find the available positioned readers:

- `CharArrayReader`
- `CharSequenceReader`
- `PagedSeqReader`
- `StreamReader`

**Addendum**

Creating one of these readers, `CharArrayReader`, e.g., is simple:

```
val car = new CharArrayReader("sample input")
```

Now you have the `Reader` to feed your parser.

Comment: Yes, thats as far as I was able to get.  Do you know how to use them to read from a, say, string with line breaks?  In such a way that they actually work (keep the position)?  As I said, StreamReader is probably out for my use case but CharArrayReader is probably right (or CharSequenceReader, which I believe is the same thing but against a Seq).

Comment: That works fine when the file is read with mkString on an InputReader.  It will retain the line numbers based on \n line breaks, which was my main concern.  In fact, its not very finicky - there are tons of ways to do this and they all seem to work.  They just aren't easy to set up properly in the REPL.  I used:

new lexical.Scanner(scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename).mkString)